# is there any option in windows registry that i can always run a program as admin without UAC and admin password

Tags: windows, registry

i am developing a desktop application.
how can i make it to always run as admin for non-admin user without UAC and admin password by making change in windows registry.
windows change registry option would be preferred but if there is any other option please tell. 
any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature.  The point of UAC is to ensure the user is aware that the program being started will have access to admin privileges.  If there were a way to turn that off, then malware would do it.

The user can disable the UAC prompts via a control panel setting, but not for a particular program.

If your program always requires admin privileges to do what it needs to do, you should have an entry in its manifest.  Modern versions of Visual Studio have options in the project settings for the executable for setting common items like this in the manifest automatically.

Comment: Another option is to leave the app unelevated and write an NT Service that does the elevated work, at the request of the unelevated app.

Comment: Thank you Adrian is there any way that UAC show but it should not ask for admin username and password